# Stereo/Audio LED "burned out"?

Tags: bmw, audio

My 1996 BMW 328i convertible still has the original stereo installed, and it DOES work, however, the LED for the controls has ceased to display anything.  Wondering if there's some magically easy fix to this, or if it means replacing the stereo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching found several options, but I am not sure if these are refering to the same radio you have. If you are not comfortable taking the radio apart there are repair services that will do it for you.

[How to fix your e36 dim radio display](http://forums.bimmerforums.com/forum/showthread.php?t=251722)

[This site offers a DIY repair kit for the back-light](http://www.carstereoremoval.com/htm/DIYBMWP.htm) if this is your radio

[image]

[They also offer a repair service](http://carstereohelp.com/bmw.htm) if that's not your radio

Other repair services include [Doctor Don's](http://www.doctordons.com/bmwradios.htm), [Radioman](http://www.radiomanrepair.com/), and [Car Radio Repair](http://www.carradiorepair.com/bmw-radio-repair). I am sure there are others as well, maybe even some local shops in your area.